# How can I know in C# if a column of a table in SQL Server is autonumeric?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access, auto-increment

I need to know in C# if a column of a Table in SQL Server 2005 is autonumeric. I know that if I make a query to get a DataTable and I go through the columns, I could use something like

```
if (table.Columns[i].AutoIncrement) bla bla
```

The problem is that AutoIncrement is always false, even when the column is an Identity and  autoincrement column, and I don't know how to find out this, besides this way.

I would like to know the same for an Access database, though.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: which query are you making against the database to populate your DataTable? Just a SELECT *... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to do is call the `GetSchema` method to retrieve also the db schema / metadata and not only the data from the database, have a look here:

[GetSchema and Schema Collections (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254934.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I have achieved what I wanted with this code
    DataTable schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
    foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
    {
        if (bool.Parse(row[schema.Columns["IsAutoIncrement"].Ordinal].ToString()))
            return true;
    }

Comment: well you have to change some objects and use Oledbconnection instead of SqlConnection, try to go like that and let us know ;-)

Comment: I've done that, but the problem is that Access returns the DataType as a number, instead of the real type, and I don't know how can I translate it

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this for `SQL Server 2005` by using the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo` namespace - [Click here for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

```
string conn = string.Format(@"Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User ID={2};Password={3}",
            "DATASOURCENAME", "DB", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");

 Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server s = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(
                    new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection(
                        new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(
                    conn)));

 Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database db =
                    s.Databases["YOUR_DATA_BASE_NAME"];
                Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Table tbl =
                    db.Tables[0];//Or you can get the table by table name

 List<Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Column> autoIncrementClmns = 
                    new List<Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Column>();

 foreach (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Column clmn in tbl.Columns)
  {
     if (clmn.IdentityIncrement > 0)//Check if this column is AutoIncrement
         autoIncrementClmns.Add(clmn);
  }
```

Needed assemblies for `SMO` are:

- Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo

Found at `YOUR_SYSTEM_DRIVE_NAME:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies\`

Comment: Sorry, I have seen your answer after the previous one, and that one is valid for me. But thank you for your help!